# can not create PointField() in GeoDjango

Tags: python, mysql, django, geodjango

I can not create my database from this sample models.py.

```
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Subscriber(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    login  = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    email  = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    country  = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Localisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    point = models.PointField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Video(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    video_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    video_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    video_file = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    video_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    video_user = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    loc = models.ForeignKey(Localisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.video_title + " / " + self.video_file
```

I get this error whatever I try (tried Stackoverflow and Google in vain) :

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 188, in get_prep_value
    raise ValueError("Couldn't create spatial object from lookup value '%s'." % obj)
ValueError: Couldn't create spatial object from lookup value 'POINT(12.4604, 43.9420)'.
```

I do not know where the value POINT((12.4604, 43.9420). I've never typed it. I guess I need to add a default value, which I tried also, by modifying the point = models.PointField() in:

```
point = models.PointField(default='POINT(0 0)
```

but the errors still occurs...

Comment: A `PolygonField` is a *collection* of points, not a single point.

Comment: For a point, you need a `PointField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#pointfield

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is what I've done, I mis copied my code (correct now), but error still occurs.

Comment: I have added:
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

and set

point = models.PointField(default=GEOSGeometry('POINT(5 23)'))

but error raised:  Invalid parameters given for Point initialization

which seems to prove that it is a matter of default value to set but can get more info now.

Answer (score -2):

The solution maybe simple, but I have to read the code itself in the API to get this information (cannot find google link).

You have to set a default value to save the PointField(). In my case, as I have no default value to enter, I should have set this: default= None

The code would look like:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    gps = models.PointField(default=None)
```